# How to show record with a fe_group restriction even though no user is logged in?

Tags: typo3, extbase, view-helpers

Could you give me a direction of think how I can make something like this -
"This extensions makes it possible to render news records with a fe_group restriction even though no user is logged in.
By using a custom ViewHelper it is possible to check in the view if the news record should be shown fully or e.g. just a teaser and a link to the login form."
From this ext - https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/main/en-us/Addons/NewsFegroupPreview/Index.html#
But not only for the news, but for my own extension and kind of records.
I've never working before with fe_groups.
As I understand all magic will be inside these "using a custom ViewHelper" ))
Where I need to change behaviour for the my content and show is as preview block, instead of standard TYPO3 behaviour.
This is TYPO3 9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restrictions should help you https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/RestrictionBuilder/Index.html#custom-restrictions

you can remove the constraint for the group and implement a custom one